# Exit the while loop if the answer invalid

Tags: python

I want the user to exit the while loop if the answer invalid. When I choose an invalid response, it changes the value of exitchoice to "EXIT", but it doesn't actually exit the loop. I am thinking it should exit the loop because the condition of the while loop being active is that exitchoice != "EXIT", therefore when it is set to "EXIT", the loop should break. Maybe I'm wrong, or that's not how python works.

```
exitchoice = "Nothing"
while exitchoice.upper() != "EXIT":
    confirm = input("Is this what you want? ")
    if confirm.upper() == "NO":
        print("Returning to selection in ")
        print("3")
        print("2")
        print("1")
    elif confirm.upper() == "YES":
        print("Enjoy your Journey...")
    else:
        print("Invalid, please try again. ")
        exitchoice = "EXIT"
    print("Continue Code blah blah blah")
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected. Can you please check again? Or re-frame your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `exitchoice` to `'EXIT'` when the input is one of the valid responses, not when it is invalid:

```
exitchoice = "Nothing"
while exitchoice.upper() != "EXIT":
    confirm = input("Is this what you want? ")
    if confirm.upper() == "NO":
        print("Returning to selection in ")
        print("3")
        print("2")
        print("1")
        exitchoice = "EXIT"
    elif confirm.upper() == "YES":
        print("Enjoy your Journey...")
        exitchoice = "EXIT"
    else:
        print("Invalid, please try again. ")
    print("Continue Code blah blah blah")
```

Alternatively, it is more idiomatic to use a `while True:` loop and `break` when conditions are satisfied:

```
while True:
    confirm = input("Is this what you want? ")
    if confirm.upper() == "NO":
        print("Returning to selection in ")
        print("3")
        print("2")
        print("1")
        break
    elif confirm.upper() == "YES":
        print("Enjoy your Journey...")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid, please try again. ")
    print("Continue Code blah blah blah")
```

Or if there are many valid responses, instead of adding `break` to every valid condition, add a `continue` to the invalid condition and let the loop `break` by default:

```
while True:
    confirm = input("Is this what you want? ")
    if confirm.upper() == "NO":
        print("Returning to selection in ")
        print("3")
        print("2")
        print("1")
    elif confirm.upper() == "YES":
        print("Enjoy your Journey...")
    else:
        print("Invalid, please try again. ")
        continue
    print("Continue Code blah blah blah")
    break
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with `String` `Class` methods.

```
while not exitchoice.upper().__eq__("EXIT"):
    # Your code inside loop
```

Change while condition with `Class` methods, and boom it will work as you expected.

Answer (score -1):

I have limited knowledge, but you wrote the exit choice in `while != Exit` loop and that will not exit because the while loop means it will execute until the condition becomes false. I think you should use a if loop and then put another if statement inside, like this:

````
    if exitchoice.upper() != "EXIT":
        confirm = input("Is this what you want? ")
        if confirm.upper() == "NO":
            print("Returning to selection in ")
            print("3")
            print("2")
            print("1")
        else confirm.upper() == "YES":
            print("Enjoy your Journey...")
   else:
       print("Invalid, please try again. ")
       exitchoice = "EXIT"
       print("Continue Code blah blah blah")```
````